# My dbContext return null, when I want get list of user, which are from identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

My dbContext return null, when I want get list of user in Index View. This list are from  my database AspNetUsers table, which has been generate by identity. I can get other my database table list.

**There is my ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductBrand> ProductBrands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order_detail> Order_Details { get; set; }
}
```

**There is my UserController**

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public UserController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _db = db;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_db.ApplicationUsers.ToList());
    }
}
```

**There is my ApplicationUser.Model, which inherit IdendityUser**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Recipe> Products { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you register `ApplicationDbContext` and Identity framework on your ASP.NET Core MVC application because you didn't show them on the question.

There are couple problems in your code.

First, if you have a custom `IdentityUser`, like the `ApplicationUser` you have, you would have to use the generic version of `IdentityDbContext`:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    ...
}
```

You would need to use the matching generic version of `IdentityDbContext` if you have any of following:

- Custom `IdentityUser`
- Custom `IdentityRole`
- Custom primary key
- All 7 classes, user and role, plus `IdentityUserRole`, `IdentityUserClaim`, `IdentityRoleClaim`, `IdentityUserLogin`, and `IdentityUserToken`

After you register your custom class with `IdentityDbContext`, you don't need to put the class as one of the `DbSet<>` there:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    ...

    public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductBrand> ProductBrands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    // public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order_detail> Order_Details { get; set; }
}
```

You would also need to use the generic version of `AddIdentity<TUser>`, `AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>`, or `AddIdentityCore<TUser>` in your `Startup.cs`, depending on what you need:

- `AddDefaultIdentity` = `AddIdentity` + `AddDefaultTokens` + `AddDefaultUI`

You didn't specify what version of ASP.NET Core Identity you're using so I don't exactly know which one you use, but the following is how I registered it:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = ...;

    ...
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I have all 7 classes customized as well as change the primary key from `string` to `Guid`.

Lastly, to use the dependency injected `UserManager` and `SignInManager`, you would need to correct generic version of them as well:

```cs
[Area("Admin")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public UserController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Get the user list
        var users = _userManager.Users.ToList();

        // Build your view model to define what your UI only needs, not just passing
        // everything to it
        var vm = new UserManagementListViewModel
        {
            Users = users.Select(x => new UserViewModel
            {
                UserId = x.Id,
                UserSurname = x.Surname,
                ProductCount = x.Products.Count(),
                OrderCount = x.Orders.Count()
            })
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```